# Save multiple worksheets as PDF

Tags: vba, excel

I'm fairly green with using VBA and this is the first time I've posted a question in this forum so bear with me if I'm breaking any posting rules.

Below is a piece of code I use to print/save 1 or more worksheets from an Excel workbook to PDF. It works fine if the data from each worksheet that I'm exporting fits onto a single page. The problem I'm finding is that if the range of data from my first sheet is larger than 1 page then only the 1st worksheet will be exported, and only up to the first page-break. Any advice or suggestions on how I can resolve this issue?

```
'Ask user if report needs to be saved as a pdf
PdfCheck = MsgBox("Save report as PDF", vbYesNo, "Save PDF") 
'use result of <PdfCheck> to control if statement
If PdfCheck = vbYes Then
    Pdfsheets = InputBox("How many worksheets would you like to include in PDF")

    'Prints the number of sheets entered by user
    'starts at first ACTIVE Worksheet to the result of <Pdfsheets>
    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    "C:\Users\" & WinName & "\Documents\REPORTING\" & Database & "\" & _
     ReportYear & "\" & FolderMonth & "\" & Database & "-" & Title & "-" & FileDate _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, From:=1, To:=Pdfsheets, OpenAfterPublish:=True
Else
    GoTo X
End If
X:
End Sub
```

Comment: *just a side note:* no need for the `Else GoTo X` and `X:` in this code, since the `If ... End If` is sufficient.

Comment: remove the `From:=1, To:=Pdfsheets,` - why restrict what pages print?

Comment: I think you may need to use the `ExportAsFixedFormat` against each worksheet. So if the users wants 2 worksheets printed, assuming they are sheets 1 and 2, you can write `Worksheets(Array(1,2)).Select ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat ....` Not sure it's the answer, but wanted to provide the possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I use, is to loop through the worksheets within the workbook and select the ones that meet my criteria. Then I use ExportAsFixedFormat to create my pdf.
Note you cannot select hidden worksheets, so if the workbook contains them you will need to add an if/then to check visibility.

```
Pdfsheets = InputBox("How many worksheets would you like to include in PDF")
    for x=1 to Pdfsheets
        thisworkbook.sheets(x).select (false) 'use false to select multiple sheets
    next x

'Prints the number of sheets entered by user--starts at first ACTIVE   
Worksheet to the result of <Pdfsheets>
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
"C:\Users\" & WinName & "\Documents\REPORTING\" & Database & "\" & ReportYear & "\" & FolderMonth & "\" & Database & "-" & Title & "-" &    FileDate _
, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```